# Bypassing invisible reCaptcha with requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, bots, recaptcha

I'm trying to make a scanner to a website using requests so the bot would be more efficient, and when I went over the Network Monitor to see the GET and POST request when emulating the process, I noticed that there's an invisible reCaptcha that prevents me to continue the process using the requests lib.

I tried simulating the exact GET and POST requests that I saw in the Network Monitor including doing it with the Session Object and saving the cookies I get, but the reCaptcha is what (I think) prevents me from actually keeping the interaction working. I tried looking for third party API, but what I understand it only works when you actually open the webdriver or you get a key to provide in the payload which in this case is not needed because the key is empty. Also I saw some solutions using selenium but I'm trying to avoid using it because it takes more time and I need to be as efficient as possible.

That's the code I tried to start the first steps:

```
import requests
from pypasser import reCaptchaV3
    
headers = {
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Host':'agendamentosonline.mne.gov.pt',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site':'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User':'?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
    'User-Agent':'what my broswer provides me'
}
    
session = requests.Session()
resp = session.get('https://agendamentosonline.mne.gov.pt/AgendamentosOnline/app/scheduleAppointmentForm.jsf',headers=headers)
    cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(session.cookies))
    recaptcha_response_1 = reCaptchaV3('https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LcKSTIfAAAAAEAxSrS8rAFiDux_eX2DBPnCXGkR&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9hZ2VuZGFtZW50b3NvbmxpbmUubW5lLmdvdi5wdDo0NDM.&hl=en&v=pn3ro1xnhf4yB8qmnrhh9iD2&size=invisible&cb=1ozwitjudoci')
    recaptcha_response_2 = reCaptchaV3('https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6Ld7jDcgAAAAAJTt2PDioLNT69IwwEPvlhqa94K7&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9hZ2VuZGFtZW50b3NvbmxpbmUubW5lLmdvdi5wdDo0NDM.&hl=pt-PT&v=pn3ro1xnhf4yB8qmnrhh9iD2&size=normal&cb=ans33lqyh70u')
    print(recaptcha_response_1) #
    print(recaptcha_response_2) #

payload_1 = {
        'javax.faces.partial.ajax': 'true',
        'javax.faces.source': 'scheduleForm:tabViewId:dataNascimento',
        'javax.faces.partial.execute': 'scheduleForm:tabViewId:dataNascimento',
        'javax.faces.behavior.event': 'blur',
        'javax.faces.partial.event': 'blur',
        'scheduleForm': 'scheduleForm',
        'javax.faces.ViewState': '-7004941669221712425:6117221410156700201',
        'scheduleForm:tabViewId:ccnum': '****',
        'scheduleForm:tabViewId:dataNascimento_input': '***',
        'scheduleForm:tabViewId_activeIndex': '0',
        'g-recaptcha-response': '',
        'scheduleForm:respV2': ''
}

resp = session.post('https://agendamentosonline.mne.gov.pt/AgendamentosOnline/app/scheduleAppointmentForm.jsf',headers=headers,data=payload_1,cookies =cookies)
      
print(resp.text)
```

It does give me a response just a different response than the one I should get when it works

Comment: What are the tries that you did? Please edit your question and provide the code you tried.

Comment: You cant just bypass it, its part of the flow so you need to find a way to solve the captcha

Answer (score -1):

it is infact totally possible to do this:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6Lc4FowfAAAAAPiXf6lyEPAe_84kesFIGdJUdRTe&co=aHR0cHM6Ly94dXNoYW54aWFuZy5jb206NDQz&hl=en&v=pn3ro1xnhf4yB8qmnrhh9iD2&size=invisible&cb=v0hsolko5hl1"
response = requests.get(url) ##get the recaptcha-token value
token = str(response.text).partition(str('id="recaptcha-token" value="'))[-1].partition(str('">'))[0] ##parse it left ot right
post = requests.post("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6Lc4FowfAAAAAPiXf6lyEPAe_84kesFIGdJUdRTe",data=f"v=UFwvoDBMjc8LiYc1DKXiAomK&reason=q&c={token}&k=6Lc4FowfAAAAAPiXf6lyEPAe_84kesFIGdJUdRTe&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9hY2NvdW50cy5zcG90aWZ5LmNvbTo0NDM.&hl=en&size=invisible&chr=%5B61%2C36%2C84%5D&vh=7349404152&bg=!d3GgcVjIAAX6VNIG-kc72sZkL7AELV23BHEg3iiH1gcAAADHVwAAAAttAQecCimhpOYJBHsHw4TnDQnJAUU1KJWxkMVvr9kGAhPbfpEnRsIzZxDoK8WNA4Xk_jX6YLNl5cj97gy8xe0qj2UogYjr5xxWaD7OHCEWXqDqFHo9zQkvm1Jr-3PhDQbPfdz_WeOLnRGfdAlF7f6kTVJj8r_mdAx3g-11hZ4fXQpAMZ0qWUVIHOx4N86v_InW_G-9vhB6bzY_Xg1rQvsjsor6h9-BUi6cUZMmvYAn78v7JLBPZSdpWYD285rwy35stcDw5cYF8ruxzI_IqsNA6NAZWA4k1n-PuM5pxQDzLsrkD5oXB839hlcFKldmlsFx074KtmlcmvUVrD2O4Q8hNqjNTjRDSRqfZzcChfvqRKsx1DyhuXnz5dYAAR1ASd47CXlwOBdU6gCke1gRtLFtfSBMDvrhg7jK3uVK3jM-0q66IZwyUZHosVS0tI6DRRdXK6owLFJZi3lLnBzbASXdOaUGQHrzDFjQAbU76NE-neuga0bExaNraPqN0wYUBz1D0IPJ5kYLPQNArW2Z9a-to_yP1Oo7IDJlty6h9jTS7D32mQinK7JskejX_kPrchsfCCmNTQVmzSVnky-3WK4okaHXDKe9EHTTD2q5yQMRKNhHiHhifVwZ7fbBuaAP36m2qOxSrjrz6Em_HkCqAQb5GArJCVq7w04FuDxW7AGg086NIlp5QkST-AkJjCxn9BnV_5_37x_K8-vkMgIgND-pOet9HMf-4yrI7QrI8odYI9mmdEHwlSbKyWBkfnWFhTTL096dlgvDsNIiPoYIqdSjRAc1hkb2ToGqHTKD9VsfpcH79bBg_reEC7EK2ifubkSRhmz_LGhlN5wRTr_DuhjO0_pH8-TGKDCLlQJQ-jWC97z979drLh97I6wuXroq3xwfymQ9iDs2glksEExM78hbfVQsdRhLiUtDFkYxjinFEb325zUQJR6xT-yXNcLfLwDLWwfL6nuLS14IXKmENSW-6OIkXXJyDhgUKW6B1Reyll5b1s9A7OpsAtQH6H5rQzm6422zF12dO9JODF4UErQv43JpQu_wYG-VRUwGWcHvcrG9vp1c8mXjNfxoE2Ok0tTNXQXLr1DacKk4mG2YZF7X8xkPjDqW1XH6w8kde64MoCbMlc2u4yv9x-44P2XXMCDppFLsRLekxW00kAXP__rWpvNoEtt4PbI_Y_d9-lSLd6WDQ5mZObuIdo6BAS095B443-CNTb_4IAp9-4puXY_WU1cbkvt0hsV9iFjkcbsjAw1xmwBZoVg1ukewp4kPWL-oVVlGJYuQm_7AvAjZ6nRIRv_f7KebJQr-bY6wD3asqUzEZ8DHOLUJeScIFtDTFzAg9SxkP1dYde7y9umqn3a_3OyFR6iulqy-c0LoULRNh1DXG4KXKaabC4f7cixdSWPazY58wiic3ysahAsbaFGv_LzwFCy7uP0M7zKiwadGSOH_gaROuLTHbRnbEvPAgaa3zyP9mFPNhy_AsgKOAy5iA4l9qaBiVXwrWpXVyuQgsliVcmpeLSrMg9fpbb7LGcLv9dz5LxUetPIDUndRuJnW6xCyNakiVQMy6vF9l9qkEoHRjua7sPWZnJC29zjHdTgEVy5SOKinYGOBs1GlCFSSyIjBWixBWXH83hCjdd3TDJjQsNtDsRMr8mVlyiEqKkIttz1-2mV2ZhA6FmJ3Ldm-tnlQN5iaIM40HKbbrHDuDKWhdWXsouO2BfLJxDDvu--e251eTYOuFIHRQzCUg-y4LddffPqdFpemjCsJC1xHTx2DQXZTdQTv9n0FK9GTwRizJxnYqn5lDoXZv4MtG4tSZFjx8U9KnNBApFcDXXfFeymVWT5miPlimr9zSBRGEdzCAv-NctpVXrSwd3Yzpsj_eGFT91owgeAzjOnPFWMod2XCZbEywubJI-0QsHFxwiGbsnXtV2fXQOzdpdQKVcynj7gQhIJHQogB0M4achR6TmT-7dRvNkffa17qyRqpoIXhbpbvC9cgQG4VQaYjlhpeiWNHM7uTW1-5cdkZOcVqxsU5c1fzMpv77BuRYm--EJpFZSfsihySlvcGWVnz1qS-deD4gGUa8un8j3v0-YAu4llS6vC9OpCb-khnh7SgHk-a19cLD9m6mXVu9EJlV2gbdMcKouobkIljeKBT6ivhkemTe_peKfgDjgFSJfJ7Hxey2LR7nG1YW2FVv6kAOPRfoHNUf2OEvUHcvZ00jc7nJZTfrt-8nmutFD9C59MQ5HWvtIK5XobaAxyunaZon6iZxiFFRDo2o-xl6TwCuHYvmVWl6mAr5kn5QDlclIKc6hrIq8osYCcukWMZhu7L9wsyVMy1WC2GhXdWlTZnaJjqLtGBsxaTCbzND4nZ0zGEsGMX180J-y1PQ3EY3nP0e4ToqO8rXPi6lZ4GmGTpm0XypZ0jkf1xnU1FacQhmpVmIKru8kbjjChfywMM2exkn3E7CINxQS77i81vn3c8fWcdvKQ9lVProo60Yzea7RpjOdnfk9T4CcjV-J941093qAttWyknhB661xBQCzOXFB0euSb8Jn-J_5tSgX4NE1AyNXQEA5wk6km6tT3UUyK3yTEn8oynK_FZz_p4W4BGy_sCUm0IG43ioT-17L2CoQAzk2ZE5g4eh7jkASVHBeXREbMWtB4YdO-gPwxIrWVVOiN57jSDi5yM08wgBqKeAVYLHXFFuUG7konyayI7tTwxYjN0j7T9nGR2Jh1wmA-q99D4tbsM2AvWIWn9j3g83JBF4nqzS4lt72WUpL3kAdbOz2xwRKaWLFaEsaM9jQeg2ijJpTNqRlKxtXneWqjkca5JZCZEmGCbplWJAEARNOEVHWd00dc2dCt8KEHiBiAP86L6loq_QvD-kbLd1bd9S8FqCMVFRcOwOOBvUEBm1D-mJiA2KWBJ9T87kcAQmLRQxrTuGHMojr9cBtKz-2afsMXRPoCPmRc-dDwiYOXUgdERgEH6lifStYMTZcjS66GGA-0UccFdY2yAl7TG6b3lDa-lbTwSJHESj_UrH3neTMf2U8Z6rFWsTIHa5XfQ8nFacgUyokFLtzxGH57QQqRUc0bfqEouu_o8S0galOM1p2uaZqrrdvAbq31i-xMU5CqW0_WVG3REfA6SY0CJLXOs8mzwGFgZJEpr374MMRL6JEUu7qd_jib4P9-O8pvKFk7tfPTccXWq12b1gj7SsA6sdeffMMG1gpD-kYGud8ghD6x9sevkZ-IRveRZQmUCqXvT6rl-YOfyBTDsv2vpqD1kXxGSNV206XBFw6bFQB583TBhFWfm3p6nc1s3p-KY4oIMR1l6Z5Ccfh7CWv7EYNkbjwfsrk1PXoI38vy4cT8ttz49TQ5WSPSBgeZuAKUlX0Hml2C2xtis_a3YABvB4UsJK65Rg7hQCWLAlX8HYLeVYiUiqh31LE5JUPayYiC0nxQADw7A6-6hFtJqQz84LrxMw7a-Q59R0VwCqWGfCebmRh_BVlg", headers={
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}) ##post the token to get the rresp token
print(post.text) #parse the token with json or what ever

##do you request
```

recaptcha v3 sucks this is a way to bypass it without paying a $. This example is based on https://xushanxiang.com/demo/recaptcha/ a demo site you can implement it for you're site by replacing the recaptcha key (k=). I hope this helps this bypass is universal and works for any site. How ever it does not work for enterprise level captcha then you need to use a solver like 2captcha.com.

Cheers!

Comment: i tried scanning the webapp and the captcha reload api is using protobuf to send data

Comment: wheres the bg data

Comment: @d-dutchview please help how to get bg data